# how to sum after group by return in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
ID amount item date
1   10     sr   21/11/2016
2   10     sr   22/11/2016
2   10     sr   22/11/2016
2   10     sr   22/11/2016
3   30     sr   22/11/2016
3   30     sr   22/11/2016
3   30     sr   22/11/2016
```

i just want return data like

```
 amount date
   10     21/11/2016
   40     22/11/2016
```

What is the best way to get it?

may be group by by date, and only i amount for one id will pick and will sum then.
Thank You in Advance.

Comment: What is the logic behind it?

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: sorry brother, i am not as expert as you.. i edited my question

Comment: which is why we suggest starting at the beginning

Comment: It seems to me amazingly unlikely that you would want to sum distinct amounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First eliminate duplicates with `DISTINCT` then a simple `GROUP BY`

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/VQL89661)**

```
 SELECT date, SUM(amount)
 FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ID, amount, item, date
        FROM YourTable ) as T
 GROUP BY date
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: what is the sigficance of T after )?

Comment: when you create a subquery, you need to name it, You can use anything to alias that subquery

Comment: my Sql Shows `An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 24)
    Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 24)
    This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "select" at position 25)
    Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 77)
    Unexpected token. (near "T" at position 79)`

Comment: Check update. Demo with the correct output is include it

Comment: While I think the premise of this query is dubious, I can't see the point of the subquery.

Comment: @Strawberry What you mean didnt see the point?

Comment: Well, how's it different from `SELECT SUM(DISTINCT amount) total, date FROM Table1 GROUP BY date;` ?

Comment: @Strawberry Because `{id:1, amount:10, date:now()} {id:2, amount:10, date:now()}` will return `10` instead of `20`?

Comment: In my case I have **joins**, to fix this "problem" I use **sub query** to eliminate duplicates like this:
`SELECT a.bla
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_with_duplicates b
ON a.foreign_key_id = b.id AND duplicated_col = (select MIN(b2.duplicated_col) from table_with_duplicates b2 WHERE a.foreign_key_id = b2.id)
WHERE ...`